# Force journald to keep logs for 30 days

Tags: systemd-journald

I am using journalctl for logging, it appears to be only keeping logs for 1 hour, how can I force it to keep 30 days of logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check your `journald.conf` file. Probably you are not using defaults values for `SystemMaxUse` or `MaxFileSec`. If you want 30 days of logs, use `MaxFileSec=30day`. Then restart the journal with `systemctl restart systemd-journald`

Also check how much space you are using for logs at the moment with `journalctl --disk-usage` and how much free space you have in your disk `df -lh`. Perhaps if you have little free space, that is triggering a vacuuming operation.